# Binding fails when moved in to constructor from app.config

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, nettcpbinding

I am trying to get rid of the app.config file for a WCF project, I need the setting to be hard-coded in to the DLL I am generating.

I created my proxy class with `svcUtil` and the client works fine when I use `App.config`

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="ManagementEndpoint">
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://example.com/MyApp/DomainManagement"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ManagementEndpoint"
        contract="MyApp.DomainManagementProxy.IDomainManagement"
        name="DomainManagementEndpoint" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

However If I remove my `App.config` and replace the default constructor with the following

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class DomainManagementClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyApp.DomainManagementProxy.IDomainManagement>, MyApp.DomainManagementProxy.IDomainManagement
{

    public DomainManagementClient() 
        : base(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, false), 
               new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://example.com/MyApp/DatabaseManagement"))
    {
    }

    //(Snip)
```

it gives me the following error as soon as I call the first method in the client

> The message with Action 'http://example.com/MyApp/DomainManagement/IDomainManagement/GetServerSetup' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

What do I need to change/put in to my constructor to be able to get the binding to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config has 'net.tcp://example.com/MyApp/DomainManagement' as the URL. But your code has 'net.tcp://example.com/MyApp/DatabaseManagement'. That could be the mismatch.

It's not a good idea to modify generated proxies. But since you have decided to hard code the URL and binding you may do like below from your application code.

```
DomainManagementClient client = new DomainManagementClient(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://example.com/MyApp/DatabaseManagement"));
```

A generated service proxy should automatically have this overload taking in the binding and address to point to.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing but I am filling in those two values from the default constructor, it will make absolutely no change to my issue.

Comment: Is your URL correct? From config it looks like : net.tcp://example.com/MyApp/DomainManagement. But in code you have net.tcp://example.com/MyApp/DatabaseManagement. DomainManagement - DatabaseManagement. From error it looks like something mismatches.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include that so it will let me change my -1 to a +1. I will accept your answer as soon as I stop hitting my head against the desk.